# tSQL - Recursive Running Total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have some data that is sorted by month. What I am trying to do is get a running total; however the total of the current month is dependent on the total of the previous month.  IE (Total of current Month) + (total of previous month).  The data that I have it like so:

```
DATE      Amount
04/2016    10.00
04/2016    25.00
05/2016    10.00
05/2016    15.00
06/2016    1.00
...
```

So that totals would should result as such

```
DATE      Totals
04/2016    35.00
05/2016    60.00
06/2016    61.00
...
```

Lets say the schema is umonth, amount in table data.  I am trying to figure this out

```
Select umonth, LAG(SUM(Amount)) Over (Partition By umonth Order by umonth) Total from data
```

I know this will not work as the `Sum(Amount)` is not a total of the sum + total of the previous month.  HELP. Is this a case for a stored procedure? So that I can set the @prevTotal to calculate into the @currTotal with a cursor - excuse my foul language.

This is on a MSSQL 2012 database.

Comment: You could join back on the same table, on the date column where it is less than or equal (<=) the current month in the `from` table, and sum column regularly.

Comment: This ended up being a larger problem than I had anticipated and was forced to usp the process as the requirements went far beyond the "rolling total" request.  Appreciate all the help, however I had already tried most of the responses prior to posting.  Closing thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a sum of LAG() unbounded.  This issue became a mute issue, once scope of the project was altered dramatically and conditions no longer required a complex rolling totals, allowing for simple rolling totals (2012 introduces LAG() and LEAD() functions making rolling totals easier, in my opinion).

Thank you for the previous suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with aggregation and a cumulative sum:

```
select umonth, 
       sum(sum(amount)) over (order by umonth) as Totals
from data
group by umonth;
```

Comment: you could even use distinct instead of group by select distinct umonth, 
       sum(amount) over (order by umonth) as Totals
from data

Answer (score 1):

Tested in and works in sql-server 2008.

```
declare @data table(Date date, amount float)

insert into @data
values('04/01/2016',10.00),
('04/01/2016',25.00),
('05/01/2016',10.00),
('05/01/2016',15.00),
('06/01/2016',1.00)

select Date, (select sum(amount) from @data d2 where d2.Date <=d1.Date) as runningTotal
from @data d1
group by date
```

in 2012, i believe you can do something like this.

```
    select Date, SUM(amount) over(order by Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECDING) as runningtotal
    from @date
group by Date
```